# Oracle 11G Xe on and off connection - ORA 12514

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I Have installed oracle xe 11g on my laptop (localhost) and frequently using it but as time flies. I'am now experiencing this error ORA 12514.. there were times that I successfully connected but most of the times I encountered an error can u help me on this I don't think having a problem in config co'z sometimes I have connection

[image]I

Comment: Do you start the database up (and shut it down) every time you do the same with the laptop? If so, be patient until database really is up, all services are started and the database registered with the listener.

Comment: Yes, ok , so how do I know if Oracle is Up? aside from successful login.

Comment: If you're connected, I'd say that it is *up*. How do you connect to it? If you provide database name in connection string ("@xe", for example), try not to specify it (i.e. provide only username and password). That should work for SQL*Plus. Though, if you use some GUI which requires the database name, then you'll have to specify it anyway.

Comment: It's now working .. I'm using sql developer... Thanks :)

Comment: Way back when I used to run the oracle database on my local windows machine, I'd have the Services list up, and watch and wait for the Oracle services to finish starting.